# Are child containers supported together with Unity in ver 2.5 of NServiceBus

Tags: unity-container, nservicebus

Are child containers supported together with Unity in ver 2.5 of NServiceBus ?
 See http://andreasohlund.net/2010/10/12/support-for-child-containers-in-nservicebus/
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/9391 .
When I use StructureMap as my IoC-container it works great and I don’t need to any special configuration. But when I use Unity as my IoC-container it won’t work at all.
Unity supports child containers, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650130.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child container support is only moving forward in v3.0 (currently the master branch).  It was enough of a breaking change to the v2.0-v2.5 branch that we didn't include it.

If you'd like to contribute some code to the project to enable child-container support in Unity, send me a pull request on the [NServiceBus](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus) project on GitHub, and I'll pull in your changes.